# How get the start and the end node of a relationship in Neo4J native fulltext index?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In Neo4J 3.5 I set up the native indexes on a certain type (:IN) of my relationships and I'm using this to query them, which works fine:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships('IN','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD relationship RETURN DISTINCT relationship;
```

However, in APOC I was able to also query the start and the end node of a relationship, using a query like:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('IN','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD start,end RETURN DISTINCT start, end;
```

Which was very helpful.

When I try to do

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships('IN','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD start, end RETURN DISTINCT start, end;
```

It doesn't work.

So what option do I have if I want to retrieve not the actual relationships, but, rather the nodes they are linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED]

This should work:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships('IN','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD relationship
RETURN DISTINCT STARTNODE(relationship) AS start, ENDNODE(relationship) AS end;
```

Comment: No, this is not working. But what works is: ` YIELD relationship WITH DISTINCT relationship, startNode(relationship) AS start, endNode(relationship) AS end RETURN start, end;` — also it's much slower than apoc.index.relationships. Do you know if it's normal?

Comment: See my updated answer, which is simpler. I do not know the internals of the 2 procedures.

Answer (score 0):

This get connected nodes

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships('IN','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD relationship, score
match (node)-[relationship]-(b)
RETURN node, b
```